# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors for dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following code

```
tourneySeeds<-read.csv("tourney_seeds.csv") 
regSeason<-read.csv("regular_season_compact_results.csv")
playoff_teams <- sort(tourneySeeds$team[which(tourneySeeds$season == "2013")])
...
#Selecting the seeds for season A
playoff_seeds <- tourneySeeds[which(tourneySeeds$season == "2013"), ]
seed_col <- vector()
BPI_col<-vector()
for(i in playoff_teams) {
  val <- match(i, playoff_seeds$team)
  seed_col <- c(seed_col, playoff_seeds$seed[val])
  BPI_col <- c(BPI_col, playoff_seeds$BPI[val])
}
#team_seed <- data.frame("Var1" = playoff_teams, "Freq" =seed_col)
team_seed<-data.frame()
team_seed <- cbind(playoff_teams, seed_col,BPI_col) 
head(team_seed$seed_col)
```

where the `tourneySeeds` data frame looks like

```
season seed team BPI
1980   W01  1207 5
1980   W02  1210 8
...
```

However, for `head(team_seed$seed_col)` I get the message `Error in team_seed$seed_col : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

why is this? I already set `team_seed` as a dataframe containing `seed_col`

Comment: A simple solution would be to use `head(team_seed[,"seed_col"])`, which will work on atomic vectors

Comment: but I don't want `team_seed$seed_col` to be an atomic vector because later in the code I used `cbind` on it and other vectors to combine them into a data frame

Comment: Check `class(team_seed)`. It will most likely say `"matrix"`. The dollar sign operator is not for matrices. Try `as.data.frame(team_seed)` if you want to use it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is relatively simple. You have

```
team_seed <- data.frame()
team_seed <- cbind(playoff_teams, seed_col, BPI_col) 
head(team_seed$seed_col)
```

If we break this down you'll see the problem:

1. You create an empty data frame and assign it to the object `team_seed`
2. You create a **matrix** by column-binding the vectors `playoff_teams`, `seed_col`, and `BPI_col`.
3. You **assign** this matrix to the object `team_seed`, thus obliterating the empty data frame you created in the first line. R just overwrote it.
4. You then try to `head()` a component of `team_seed` but R rightly complains that this is an atomic vector (a matrix is a vector with a `dim` attribute)

What you want is some variation on:

```
team_seed <- data.frame(playoff_teams, seed_col, BPI_col)
```

there is no reason to allocate the empty data frame. If you do that, then you need to fill in the data frame, not overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last two lines of code to these instead:

```
team_seed <- data.frame(playoff_teams, seed_col,BPI_col) 
head(team_seed$seed_col)
```

It seems like you overwrite your data.frame with a matrix in your example

Does it work?